# What gem produces this output '\_ Called from:'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, output

I started working on a existing rails project and in the rails server output there are these extra lines:

```
User Load (10.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'miles@milestshirts.com' LIMIT 1
\_ Called from: app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `block in <class:ApplicationController>'
```

Basically for each SQL query in my rails app it adds a line who called it.
I can't seem to find it in the Gemfile as it has over a 150 gems.

And it is not https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace

Comment: Maybe list the gems in your Gemfile.lock ? (perhaps omitting the ones that are definitely not it). Are you sure it is not something in the app?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Active Record Query Trace](https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace):

> When enabled every query source will be logged like:

```
  IntuitAccount Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "intuit_accounts".* FROM "intuit_accounts" WHERE "intuit_accounts"."user_id" = 20 LIMIT 1
Called from:
  app/views/users/edit.html.haml:78:in `block in _app_views_users_edit_html_haml___1953197429694975654_70177901460360'
  app/views/users/edit.html.haml:16:in `_app_views_users_edit_html_haml___1953197429694975654_70177901460360'
```

Comment: This project was abandoned for a while but now it is maintained again and just got a couple of new releases.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in projects lib folder. If anyone is interesed here is a simple code:

```
module QueryTrace
  def self.enable!
    ::ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.send(:include, self)
  end

  def self.append_features(klass)
    super
    klass.class_eval do
      unless method_defined?(:log_info_without_trace)
        alias_method :log_info_without_trace, :sql
        alias_method :sql, :log_info_with_trace
      end
    end
  end

  def log_info_with_trace(event)
    begin
    log_info_without_trace(event)
    trace_log = Rails.backtrace_cleaner.clean(caller).first
    if trace_log && event.payload[:name] != 'SCHEMA'
      logger.debug("   \\_ \e[33mCalled from:\e[0m " + trace_log)
    end
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```